# Set a private var by an anonymous class in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, abstract-class, mixins

I found an example about abstract type member in Odersky's paper (Chapter 2.1): http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.pdf

[image]

---

I paste it below

```
abstract class AbsCell {
  type T
  val init: T
  private var value: T = init
  def get: T = value
  def set(x:T):Unit = {value = x}
}


val cell = new AbsCell{ type T=Int; val init=1}
cell.set(cell.get + 1)
cell.get
```

The codes doesn't work as expected in the latest Scala (Scala Version: 2.11).

I found the value of the last expression `cell.get` is 1, while what I expected is 2. The reason is that the `private var value: T = init` doesn't work well for the mixin anonymous class  `{ type T=Int; val init=1}`.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: There are no mixins in this question. It is a regular anonymous class. Also, I wouldn't put the Java-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because `value` is initialized *before* the `val init` is. So at the time `value` is initialized, `init` is still equal to the default value of type `T`, which is 0 for `T = Int`.

You can fix this by making `init` a `def` or a `lazy val`.

Note that the paper you reference does not have the code you mention. In the paper, `init` is a parameter to the constructor of `GenCell`/`AbsCell`, and is therefore initialized properly before `value` is.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the paper where the codes come from: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B2x3i.png   I didn't find the `init` in the constructor of `AbsCell`